# jQuery slideToggle() peculiar behaviour in Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, slidetoggle

I am having a problem in Chrome when I slideToggle() and  element.

EDIT: Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Awuua/), click Link A a few times and you'll see what I mean.

The HTML is along the lines of:

```
<div>
    <a>Link A</a>
    <a id="myLink">Link B</a>
</div>
```

With very simple CSS floating all the links to the left horizontally:

```
a{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

#myLink{
   display: none; 
}
```

The JavaScript simply toggles between showing myLink and hiding it on some event.

```
$('#myLink').slideToggle();
```

When slideToggle() is called the first time, everything works nicely; the link appears horizontally aligned with the other link. However, if I hide it again, when it reappears in Chrome/Safari the link appears underneath the other link (instead of alongside it). Also, I've noticed if I use the Developer Tools in Chrome and click on the element, it fixes itself and moves the link to be horizontally inline with the other link.

Anyone know of any issues with slideToggle() in WebKit?

Comment: setup and example here http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: also is something very funny, in chrome, when I inspect the "Link B"  rises that element next to the "Link A"

Comment: @MCSI yeah I experience the same thing. However, in Firefox it was fine. Adding a width to my wrapper div fixed the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't float `DIV` or you can give it a width in pixels.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Diodues, is there anyway to get around the issue without using an unsized float as I require it to be a float without a width.

Comment: Use inline-block for your A-tag instead of float, but that won't work with IE 6 or 7. Your choice.